# Something unknown happened with a simple CREATE statement in Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

One day, I accidently issued a CREATE statement on SQL prompt in Oracle 9i with all columns enclosing within double quotation marks as below.

```
 CREATE TABLE emp("emp_id" VARCHAR2(6) primary key, 

"emp_name" VARCHAR2(30) not null, "salary" NUMBER);
```

---

instead of issuing it as the one mentioned below without enclosing the column names within quotation marks as usual.

```
CREATE TABLE emp(emp_id VARCHAR2(6) primary key, 

emp_name VARCHAR2(30) not null, salary NUMBER);
```

---

This simple query (first mentioned) worked just fine with no problem at all and the emp table was created successfully just then I have created three rows into this table with the following INSERT command.

```
INSERT INTO emp VALUES("E0001", "Henery", 50000);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES("E0002", "Alex", 65000);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES("E0003", "Peter", 70000);
```

---

Three rows created successfully into the emp table. I then executed a SELECT statement to verify whether they were created or not and found that they were indeed created.

```
SELECT * FROM emp;
```

---

but when I executed the SELECT statement like the one below

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_name, salary FROM emp;
```

I made sure that though, I had used the same column names as they were actually in the emp table, Oracle issued an error indicating that "Such columns don't exist."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [SQL Language Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#i27570):

> "A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks (").
>   If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must
>   use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object."

Comment: Yes absolutely right, when I tried this version of SQL [SELECT "emp_id", "emp_name", "salary" FROM emp;], it worked. I also came to know that the Oracle engine converts each column name to capital letter before compiling an SQL statement and if the column names (objects) are enclosed within double quotation marks, Oracle engine will be unable to convert them into uppercase and hence, it will not locate such column names which are enclosed within double quotation marks and in small case letters and an attempt to compile such an SQL will cause an error!